# Unsuccessfull "if" statement, to match 2 values in PHP

Tags: php

```
<html>
  <a href="/">
    <button>
    Home
    </button>
  </a>
  <br>
  Login:
  <br>
  <br>
  <form method="POST">
    Username
    <br>
    <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="Username">
    <br>
    <br>
    Password
    <br>
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="Password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button> Login </button>
  </form>
  <?php
    $pass_detect = False;
    $user["username"] = $_POST["Username"];
    $user["password"] = $_POST["Password"];
    if (!empty($user["username"]) and !empty($user["password"])) {
      if(strpos(file_get_contents("secure/users.txt"),$user["username"]) !== false) {
          $search = $user["username"];
          $lines = file('secure/users.txt');
          $line_number = false;
          while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {
           $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? $key + 1 : $line_number;
            }
          $line_number = $line_number-1;
          $lines = file('secure/pass.txt');
          $pass_detect = $lines[$line_number];
        if ($pass_detect == $user["password"]) {
          echo "Login Successfull!";
        } else {
          echo "Invalid Password!";
        }
        
    } else {
      echo "Invalid account";
    }
    } else {
      echo "Username or Password is empty!";
    }
  ?>
<br>
  <br>
  Don't have an account?
  <br>
  Join the development team.
  <br>
  <a href="request-dev.php">
  <button>
    Sign up
  </button>
</a>
</html>
```

On line 39, I'm detecting 2 values, and even though they're the same, it still outputs "false". I also tried it with "===", however it still outputs the same result. I'm curious as to why those 2 values do not match, even though when I echoed them, they outputed the same value.

I was expecting the if satement, on line 39, to output "true"!

Comment: Hard to tell. Try `var_dump($pass_detect); var_dump($user['password']);` to check the contents and the string length for both.

Comment: Thanks! The string length of $pass_detect is 6, and for $user["password"] it's 5. Turns out that $pass_detect contains a space at the end. Thanks!

Comment: Try `$pass_detect = trim($lines[$line_number]);` A line in a file will have a new line character `\n` you need to trim it off.

Comment: I just used:
`$pass_detect = trim($pass_detect);`
 Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pass_detect = trim($pass_detect);`
Turns out that `$pass_detect` had an unnecessary space in it.
Thanks to:
`@aynber` and
`@Arleigh Hix`
for helping me answer my question!  -- Stack overflow says that I can accept my answer in 2 days.

Answer (score -3):

switch ($var) {
case "abc":
case "def":
case "hij":
echo "yes";
break;
default:
echo "no";
}

Comment: Thanks for answering, however it turns out that I just had to trim the `$pass_detect` variable. But, thanks for your contributions!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).